# Having one class in one of two one-to-many relationships (eg: Comments on Video OR Image) in Grails?

Tags: grails, entity-relationship, many-to-one

Im building an example where there exists Video and Image domain models. Each have a one-to-many relationship with the Comment model as follows:

```
package commentstest

class Video {

    static constraints = {
        embeddUrl(blank:false,nullable:false,url:true)
    }

    String embeddUrl

    static hasMany = [comments:Comment]
}
```

and

```
package commentstest

class Image {

    static constraints = {
        fileName(blank:false,nullable:false)
    }

    String fileName

    static hasMany = [comments: Comment]
}
```

and finally the Comment class

```
package commentstest

class Comment {

    static constraints = {
        body(blank:false,nullable:false)
    }

    String body

    static belongsTo = [image:Image, video:Video]
}
```

Now the problem i'm having is that when i create a 'comment' it must be able to be added to either a video OR an image. Currently, the scaffolding populates both the image and video option, and doesnt give the option to leave empty for one of those fields.

Anyone have an idea how to do this? Im sure my problems are spawning from the line:

```
static belongsTo = [image:Image,video:Video]
```

But i dont know how to specify that it must belong to one OR the other. not both.

Comment: I don't know if it works, didn't test it

You can provide constraints to these attributes
    
    `class Face {
        static hasOne = [nose:Nose]

        static constraints = { nose unique: true } 
    }`

A `blank:true` constraint could be helpful. But, you have to make sure on of them is provided.
It's a kind of work-around, like treating the symptoms and not the cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could see and understand, it's like you say`static belongsTo = [image:Image,video:Video]` is the root cause.

What you should do is add something like this to your constraints in Comment

```
   static constraints = {
        fileName(blank:false,nullable:false)
        image(nullable:true)
        video(nullable:true)
    }
```

That enables you to set it to either a video or image.

Hope it hepls!